# How do I refresh the JavaScript in the primary content pane in IE developer tools when debugging?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, ie-developer-tools

I'm in the middle of writing/testing JavaScript code.

I'm using IE9 Developer Tools to debug the JavaScript. When I make a change to the code, refresh the page (Ctrl+F5), and click "Stop Debugging", the JavaScript in the primary content pane is updated. However, when I click "Start Debugging" to test the new code, the content pane reverts to the previous code.

I've tried clearing the browser cache, but this does not resolve the problem.

The only way I can resolve this right now is by restarting the browser, but that is not acceptable, as I shouldn't have to shut down the browser, and then login to the website again just to test changing one line of code.

Comment: Isn't there a refresh icon on the script tab of the developer tools?

Comment: It's not acceptable, but then this is IE we are talking about so.... Jokes aside you should be able to do this, I do it all the time, but I'm also developing in ruby on rails and it has some automagick, which could be the reason it works for me. Let me do some digging on this one.

Comment: @jalynn2 no, there is no "refresh" button